# regular expression for ip v4

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing an ip v4 validator program with javascript.
The ip has to be between the range of `1.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`
My problem is that I also get the `0.0.0.0` and should not take it.

I leave you my regular expression:

```
Var Expression1 = new RegExp ("[0-9] | [1-9] [0-9] | 1 [0-9] {2} | 2 [0-4] [0-9] | 25 [0-5]) [3] ([0-9] | [1-9] [0-9] | 1 [0-9] {2} | 2 [0-4] [0-9] ] | 25 [0-5]) $ ");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "not 0.0.0.0" negative lookbehind (`^(?!0\.0\.0\.0)`) at the beginning of the line:

```
^(?!0\.0\.0\.0)(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dIkHRJ/2

P.S.

Please notice your regex is incomplete and broken. Use the corrected one from the sample above.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a function, it will be clearer not using a regex:

```js
function validateIP(ip) {
  var p = ip.split('.');                               // split it by '.'
  if(p.length !== 4) return false;                     // if there is not for parts => false
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)                           // for each part
    if(isNaN(p[i]) || i < 0 || i > 255) return false;  // if it's not a number between 0 - 255 => false
  
  return p[3] > 0;                                     // return true if the last part is not 0, false otherwise
}

alert(validateIP(prompt("IP: ")));
```

Comment: Although the idea is sane, you'd have to put more work in it, consider e.g. `2e1.2e2.2e1.2e0`

Comment: @georg Yeah! Adding the support for that in this is much easier than add it to a regex!

Answer (score 0):

The more accurate solution using `RegExp.prototype.test()`, `String.prototype.split()` and `Array.prototype.every()` functions:

```js
var re = /^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/,
    validateIPv4 = function(ip) {
        return re.test(ip) && ip.split('.').every(function(d, idx){
                var octet = Number(d);
                if (idx === 0) {
                    return octet > 0;
                }
                return 0 <= octet && octet <= 255;
            });
    };

console.log(validateIPv4('0.0.0.0'));
console.log(validateIPv4('1.0.0.0'));
console.log(validateIPv4('127.0.0.1'));
console.log(validateIPv4('255.255.255.255'));
```